# Correct way to deploy a Restful WCF service

Tags: iis, wcf-rest

I've created a simple RESTFul WCF service that returns JSON formatted data.

This works swimmingly when I'm hosting it in my dev environment.

I use the following uri format:

```
http://localhost:8732/Service1/GetMetric?RunNumber=49653&MetricName=Res_Side_Coeff&SampleNumber=2
```

My problems begin when I want to host it on a server. If I publish it, an svc file is created. This is no use as I have to create a wsdl, which is fine for a VS C# project to bind to, but not for me as the consumer of this is going to be an external, non c# tool. Therefore I just want to keep the access to it exactly the same as when in development.

How do you deploy to an IIS server (8.5) to achieve this and what configuration settings do I need?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try to create a WCF Service application rather than a library, this works fine, though I still dont know why the library doesn't work.